# How to see the path of the JS file in Chrome Dev tool

Tags: google-chrome

I have js file opened that has a bug under the chrome js dev tool under 'source' tab, but i  don't see a way to locate the full path for this file, how can i? there is a file tree on the left, but it doesn't show the location of the file i have currently open. what am i missing? Thank you for help

Comment: move to the console tab, then double click the red error x(or yellow warning sign) repeatedly it should open the js file to exact line where the exception occured, but this isn't always the location of the error in your script, but you can usually backtrace it from there if you're competent. depending on the severity of the error, it may open the file and just show blank white space.

Comment: thank you r3wt. Alicides answer the question very well

Comment: no problem, i'm glad you got it resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your mouse pointer over the tab with the name of the current open file, a tooltip will be shown, with the full URL to the file.

[image]

Comment: It didn't work for me in Chrome, but worked in Firefox, thanks!